# Convert Javascript onkeypress to knockoutjs to call on enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am trying to do everthing I can in KnockoutJS however I am having a hard time getting this to convert to knockoutjs.

I have an input box that upon enter press I need to call addInputName().  This is kind of the old school way I think to do it.  Is there a way to do this all in knockout?

```
<input id="inputName" onkeypress="addInputName(this, event);" />
<input id="addInputName" type="button" data-bind="event: { click: addInputName }" value="Add" />


self.addInputName = function (inputElement, event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) { 
        $('#addInputName').click();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// View
<input id="inputName" data-bind="value: name, enterKey: addInputName" />
<input id="addInputName" type="button" data-bind="click: addInputName" value="Add" />

// ViewModel
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.name = ko.observable();
  self.names = ko.observableArray();
  self.addInputName = function () {
    self.names.push(self.name());
    self.name("");
  };
}

// Custom Binding
ko.bindingHandlers.enterKey = {
  init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, data, context) {
    var wrapper = function (data, event) {
      if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        valueAccessor().call(this, data, event);
      }
    };
    ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { event: { keyup: wrapper } }, context);
  }
};
```

[Custom Bindings](http://vimeo.com/73627803) @20:05

Look into [Custom Bindings](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html).  It's an invaluable tool to help get UI logic out of your ViewModel's business logic.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just wrap the inputs inside a form? Then you can change your HTML to

```
<form data-bind="submit: addInputName">
    <input id="inputName" type="text" data-bind="value: name" />
    <input id="addInputName" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Then your KO viewmodel looks something like

```
var ViewModel = function()
{
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable();
    self.addInputName = function() {
        // do stuff
    }   
}
```

Comment: Yes, if the browser's willing to do some bit of work for you (like recognizing the enter key in a form field) it's almost always a good idea to let it do so instead of trying to duplicate it yourself. Less code to write, and less code to go wrong.

Comment: This is a good answer to a question about combining form submission with knockout.js; however, the question is about how to add a name to a list of names and not how to submit the form's data. The `addInputName` button is not a submit button but an event to add that `inputName` to that list of names.  How submission is handled is up to you.  Even with KO's `submit` binding, the default form submission is disabled unless `addInputName` returns `true`. Check out this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/180GBazvexrplZDEJkK4?p=preview