# Binding input enter to function call using knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to have an `input` element call a function when I press enter and use the value in the element:

```
<input id="searchQuery" placeholder="Search..." type="text" data-bind="value: searchQuery, valueUpdate: 'onkeydown', event: { keydown: searchQueryEntered }"/>
```

The function:

```
searchQueryEntered = function (value, event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13)
       ...do some stuff...
},
```

My function *does* get called, but `searchQuery` is never updated! I can't even type anything into the `input`. Somehow it's getting thrown out. What I'm trying to do seems pretty simple to me but I haven't been able to get it right.

Comment: Try to use `afterkeydown` instead of `onkeydown` in valueUpdate binding.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Javascript onkeypress to knockoutjs to call on enter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18662710/convert-javascript-onkeypress-to-knockoutjs-to-call-on-enter)

Answer (score 0):

To fix your input you need to return true from your keydown handler:

```
    searchQueryEntered = function (value, event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
           ...do some stuff...
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Then you should use valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown' to make your model be updated after each keydown.

Check out this working example: http://jsfiddle.net/tabalinas/h4u8E/

Answer (score 0):

Register a bindinghandler for the enter key

```
ko.bindingHandlers.onEnterKey = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, vm) {
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "keyup", function(event) {
            if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                ko.utils.triggerEvent(element, "change");
                valueAccessor().call(vm, vm);
            }

            return true;
        });
    }         
};
```

then you can bind as follow  `onEnterKey: searchQueryEntered`

see fiddle below
http://jsfiddle.net/NccZ8/2/